# Sort object by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, object

So here's the object:

[image: Object structure]

As you can see, the last amount(2000) is lower than 10000 but it's still at the end. I'm trying to display the elements sorted by amount. I know that I have to convert the object to array and use sort on it, but don't have an idea how can I do this properly.

EDIT: I've tried something like this without any success:

```
var packs_array = [];

jQuery.each(json.purchase_packs, function(i, pack) {
    packs_array.push(pack);
});

packs_array.sort();
```

Comment: you need to convert the object to a array before sorting because object doesnot have an order

Comment: `amount` is an integer, right?

Comment: Are you using the values in DOM elements, if so show us how, and it's probably easier to create an array of elements, and insert them into the DOM in the right order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value

Comment: @floww, yes, it's an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var packs = {
    0: { amount: 2000 },
    3: { amount: 1000 },
    5: { amount: 50 }
};

var sortedPacks = Object.keys(packs)
    .map(function (id)  {
        packs[id].id = parseInt(id, 10);
        return packs[id];
    })
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.amount - b.amount;
    });

console.log(sortedPacks); // => [{"amount":50,"id":5},{"amount":1000,"id":3},{"amount":2000,"id":0}]
```

Comment: Note: This snipped uses ES5 features. If you are targeting browsers like IE8 and earlier, you should include a ES5 shim like [Augment.js](http://augmentjs.com/) or [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) in your page.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to convert your object into an array first...

```
var arr = $.map(json.purchase_packs, function(v) { return v; });
```

... then sort this array with a custom sorter function:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.amount - b.amount;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G49TF/). Note that sorting is in-place operation (i.e., `arr.sort` alters an existing object).

Comment: How can access the ID of the object after the sorting?
I mean 93 for amount = 2000.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript `sort()` function works with list elements as strings by default. You should specify sort function to sort other value types:

```
var l = [1, 5, 12, 127, 12, 3, 9];
l.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
=> [ 1, 3, 5, 9, 12, 12, 127 ]
```

*[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)*